# Sharepoint2010: ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range

Tags: sharepoint-2010

I have a lookup column 'usertype' in one of my list, that is lookup for another list. and in my code when i try to access this column,    `item["usertype"]`
i get an error: **ArgumentException: Value does not fall within the expected range.**

I tried with Lookup **Resource Throttling** in **Central Administration**.
But still i am not able to access this field.
And this field is not programmatically created.

Any idea to solve this..

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution.
Go through the below link.

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/sharepoint/en-US/567ed634-0433-4e6a-85e4-b35574f5db21/sharepoint2010-argumentexception-value-does-not-fall-within-the-expected-range?forum=sharepointcustomizationlegacy&prof=required

Comment: Please don't just provide a link only answer, instead post your answer here.